# How to install .ttf font files using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, fonts, truetype

I wanted to install `.ttf` font file on **windows/linux/mac** with Nodejs, I googled but the only thing I found was [installfont](https://github.com/matsilva/installfont) which has used `vbscript`, Is there a way to install `.ttf` with `Nodejs` using (`javascript`/`typescript`) code?

Comment: You need to get nodejs to `exec` a cmd shell and then give that shell some arcane windows commands.  [Read this](https://superuser.com/questions/201896/how-do-i-install-a-font-from-the-windows-command-prompt). The shell may need elevated privileges.

Comment: @O.Jones I want a cross-platform solution...

Comment: Then use the `os` package to check what platform you are on and `exec` the respective command. I doubt there is a ready to use cross-platform TTF Installer for nodejs yet ...